# Custom block duplicating Product View using local.xml

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view, custom-block

I'm trying to add a new block to the Product View page using my local.xml file, within this file I have the following:

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
            <block type="underlay_products/carpets" name="catalog.product.carpet_underlay" as="carpet_underlay" template="catalog/product/views/partials/carpet_underlay.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Which adds the block, but it's in the wrong place and duplicates the product view page (there's 2 images, 2 product names, etc) and my block is at the bottom when it should be in a different place.

However, if I add this line to my catalog.xml file underneath the related_products block it works absolutely fine, the content is in the right place and there's no duplication of the product:

```
 <block type="underlay_products/carpets" name="catalog.product.carpet_underlay" as="carpet_underlay" template="catalog/product/views/partials/carpet_underlay.phtml"/>
```

Any ideas why this happens and I can use my local.xml file instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you have the catalog view twice is because you wrap your code with the following.

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
```

What you can do is call reference to use the current block.

```
<reference name="product.info">
     <block type="underlay_products/carpets" name="catalog.product.carpet_underlay" as="carpet_underlay" template="catalog/product/views/partials/carpet_underlay.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Comment: Oh bloody hell, you're right. Rather than using `reference` in my local.xml I was still trying to use `block`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for re-defining

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
```

in local.xml, All you need is to add your block to existing block. Below should work ( I have not tested though )

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
  <reference name="product.info">
       <block type="underlay_products/carpets" name="catalog.product.carpet_underlay" as="carpet_underlay" template="catalog/product/views/partials/carpet_underlay.phtml"/>
  </reference> 
</catalog_product_view>
```